# OpenGL window not opening process terminating on eclipse cdt

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

When i run this project nothing happens. Nothing is sent to the console either. I'm on windows

In the libraries settings in eclipse, I have opengl32, glu32, and freeglut.

```
/*
 * GL01Hello.cpp: Test OpenGL/GLUT C/C++ Setup
 * Tested under Eclipse CDT with MinGW/Cygwin and CodeBlocks with MinGW
 * To compile with -lfreeglut -lglu32 -lopengl32
 */
#include <windows.h>  // for MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>  // GLUT, include glu.h and gl.h
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

/* Handler for window-repaint event. Call back when the window first appears and
   whenever the window needs to be re-painted. */
void display() {
   glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer (background)

   // Draw a Red 1x1 Square centered at origin
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
      glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
      glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);    // x, y
      glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
      glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
      glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
   glEnd();

   glFlush();  // Render now
}

/* Main function: GLUT runs as a console application starting at main()  */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
   glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
   glutInitWindowSize(320, 320);   // Set the window's initial width & height
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
   glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
   glutMainLoop();           // Enter the event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which FreeGLUT version are you using?  Anything change if you switch to `GLUT_DOUBLE` & `glutSwapBuffers()`?

Comment: Both glu and all the `glBegin`/`glVertex`/`glEnd` way of doing things have been deprecated for decades, this won't work in a forward-compatible modern OpenGL context.

Comment: My bet would be that it doesn't find the freeglut DLL, but what exit code do you get when when running this in eclipse?

Comment: @derhass  exit value: -1,073,741,515 and nothing gets sent to the console using cout even if i do it at the top of main. Im usin glew now and its the same problem as before

Comment: `-1,073,741,515` is `C0000135` which is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND` so it is exactly the error I had guessed. "Im usin glew now and its the same problem as before" GLEW is not a replacement for GLUT, so what you say does not make any sense.

Comment: For glew, I put the .lib file in my lib folder of mingw, but Im still getting the same error. How would I fix this?